# How to get another value from AutoComplete TextView item selected using retrofit

Tags: java, android

I am using an Autocomplete Textview which shows name from database. I want to show a price in a textview which I selected from autocomplete textview.

```
public void paket_data() {
    ApiRequest PaketDataActivity = Retroserver.getClient().create(ApiRequest.class);
    Call<ResponsPaketData> callPaket = PaketDataActivity.getPaketData();
    callPaket.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsPaketData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponsPaketData> call, Response<ResponsPaketData> response) {
            ResponsPaketData responsePaketData = response.body();
            ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (PaketData paketData : responsePaketData.getResult()){
                stringList.add(paketData.getNama_paket());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
                    (mContext, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, stringList);
            etPaket.setThreshold(1); //will start working from first character
            etPaket.setAdapter(adapter);

            etPaket.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponsPaketData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```